# ORACLE Why alias COUNTER is an invalid ID in my case counter > 0?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, case, alias

```
select demvbtn, 
       deomsch,
       (select count(*)
          from drmvctl a, drmvtbg b
         where a.deblgty = b.demvbtn
           and a.deblgty = :demvbtn) as counter,
       case 
         when counter > 0 
         then 'u'
         else ''
       end ctrl
from drmvtbg
where demvbtn = :demvbtn
```

Comment: That is how SQL works.  You cannot re-use a column alias in the same `select`.   You need to use a subquery, CTE, or lateral join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want:

```
select demvbtn, deomsch, counter,
       (case when counter > 0 then 'u'
        end) as ctrl
from (select dt.demvbtn, dt.deomsch,
             (select count(*)
              from drmvctl dc
              where dc.deblgty = dt.demvbtn and
                    dc.deblgty = dt.demvbtn
             ) as counter
      from drmvtbg dt
      where dt.demvbtn = :demvbtn
     ) d;
```

Notes:

- Use table aliases to identify the tables and qualify all column names.
- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- In this case, you would seem to want a correlated subquery, rather than a `JOIN`.
- The `else` is unnecessary for the `case` expression.

Answer (score 2):

The `counter` alias is not available for use in the same level `select` clause, because when that select is evaluated, `counter` has not been computed.  One solution here is to use a CTE which first computes the `counter` alias term:

```
with cte as (
    select demvbtn, deomsch,
        (select count(*) from drmvctl a inner join drmvtbg b
         on a.deblgty = b.demvbtn where a.deblgty = :demvbtn) as counter
    from drmvtbg
    where demvbtn = :demvbtn
)

select demvbtn, deomsch, counter,
    case when counter > 0 then 'u' else '' end ctrl
from cte;
```

Note that I also removed your old school style comma join with a modern explicit inner join.  This is the preferred way of writing a join these days.

Answer (score 1):

use subquery as column alias is not working in same select

```
select *,
       case 
         when counter > 0 
         then 'u'
         else ''
       end ctrl from
(
select demvbtn, 
       deomsch,
       (select count(*)
          from drmvctl a join drmvtbg b
         on a.deblgty = b.demvbtn
           where a.deblgty = :demvbtn) as counter
from drmvtbg
where demvbtn = :demvbtn
)A
```

Answer (score 1):

inline alias does not support in oracle use subquery

```
    select emvbtn, 
           deomsch,case 
             when counter > 0 
             then 'u'
             else ''
           end ctrl
  from (select demvbtn, 
           deomsch,
           (select count(*)
              from drmvctl a join drmvtbg b
             on a.deblgty = b.demvbtn
               where a.deblgty = :demvbtn) as counter           
    from drmvtbg
    where demvbtn = :demvbtn
 ) t
```